# Согласование числа глагола с несколькими словами в ед. числе

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

У меня болит рука. У меня болят руки.
Но: **У меня *болит (болят)* рука и нога.**

Как будет правильно?

Comment: Теория здесь: §190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта правильны. Вообще-то болят две конечности, а если сказуемое в препозиции и предметов два, то сказуемое ставится во множественном числе.

Но есть и такой пункт: Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих, например:
          1) сказуемое предшествует подлежащим: На стене висела винтовка и высокая казацкая шапка (Пушкин); В нём (Пушкине), как будто в лексиконе, заключалось всё богатство, сила и гибкость нашего языка (Гоголь); Главной заботой была кухня и обед (Гончаров); И с берега, сквозь шум машины, неслось рокотание и гул (Короленко); Да здравствует дружба и солидарность народов! Однако в деловой речи предпочитается форма множественного числа, например: На пушной рынок поставлены каракуль и лисьи шкурки; Работают завод, электростанция и несколько комплексов.

У нас не деловая речь, сказуемое предшествует подлежащим, их смысловая близость неоспорима - это две конечности. Значит, предпочтительно единственное число: *У меня болит рука и нога.*

Но это не обязательно, а предпочтительно. Выбор за автором. В бытовой речи я бы выбрала единственное число, но это лично мой выбор.

Comment: Если сказуемое стоит в препозиции, то, по Розенталю, предпочтительно единственое число, разве не так?

Comment: Так, но это "обычно", т.е. никаких других условий нет, а потом ещё  несколько пунктов с подробностями. У нас вот смысловая близость даёт предпочтение ед. числу, а два участника событий - множественному.

Answer (score 1):

**У меня болит рука и (болит) нога.**

Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими делается с учетом разных факторов (сказуемое может стоять в форме мн. или ед. числа).

Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается **при смысловой близости** однородных подлежащих, причем сказуемое может находиться как перед однородным рядом, так и после него. Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Можно добавить и другие (индивидуальные) факторы: это мало распространенное предложение, в котором  разная форм числа  для рядом стоящих слов напрягает слух, особенно если это касается парных предметов: руки, ноги.

Также боль в руке и ноге ощущается по отдельности, нет общего действия.

Comment: А можете мне еще посоветовать, я знаю что правильно будет русский и английский языки - слово языки в мн. числе, то же самое будет и со словом цвет? Например: черный и белый цвета

Comment: Можно посмотреть в Нацкорпусе: Сверяются русский и английский тексты. Официальными языками являются русский и английский языки. Стены в ее комнате покрашены в черный и белый цвета. Надо  поменять местами черный и белый цвета.  Как мы видим, используется мн. число. Объяснить это можно так: препозиция определений и их самостоятельность, разделенность. Сравнить: мне нравится сочетание черного и белого цветов (цвета разделены). Мне  больше всего нравится черный и белый цвет (общее предпочтение).