# Как правильно: "Лежит ноутбук и два планшета" или "Лежат ноутбук и два планшета"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно сказать: "На столе **лежит** ноутбук и два планшета" или "На столе **лежат** ноутбук и два планшета"?

Answer (score 2):

Если это протокол осмотра комнаты – однозначно второй вариант. Если бытовая речь – предпочтение первому.

Answer (score 1):

**На столе лежат ноутбук и два планшета.**

Это тема §190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими.http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Обычно делается выбор ед. или мн.числа сказуемого, связанный с влиянием различных факторов (например, при препозиции сказуемого чаще используется ед. число), но здесь мн. число сказуемого ***лежат*** определяется тем, что второе подлежащее имеет форму мн. числа (два планшета).

**Примечание**.

В то же время **влияние мн. числа одного из подлежащих** не является однозначным.

У Розенталя: На согласование сказуемого может оказать влияние наличие среди подлежащих формы множественного числа: В постель ее **уложили ревность и слезы** (Чехов). Но и в этом случае возможна форма единственного числа сказуемого: **Несся** тяжелый топот кованых сапог и **крикливые бабьи взвизги** (Серафимович).

Думаю, что вариант с ед. числом сказуемого здесь является особым случаем:  (1) влияние первого определения "тяжелый"в форме ед. ч.; (2) семантика сказуемого здесь имеет оттенок  обобщенности (несся поток звуков);

Comment: Вы на какой подпункт ссылаетесь? Мне пришлось перечитать всё и там (по Вашей ссылке) в конце п.190.3.2) сказано, что множественное число одного из подлежащих не обязательно влечёт форму множественного числа сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо, я учла ваше замечание в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта правильны. Подробно этот вопрос разобран у Розенталя ([§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)). На принятие решения влияет несколько притовоположно направленных факторов.

Свобода выбора не ограничена тем, что второе подлежащее имеет форму мн. числа (два планшета), вот похожий пример, который приводит Розенталь:

> До Райского и Марфиньки **долетел** грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные **голоса**, внезапно притихшие... (Гончаров);

По-моему, если взгляд наблюдателя скользит по столу и в поле зрения попадет сначала ноутбук, а потом два планшета, то нужно ставить ед. ч. Если нужно просто привести список лежащих на столе предметов, то чаша весов склоняется к мн. ч.

Сошлюсь еще на Людмилу: "В бытовой речи я бы выбрала единственное число, но это лично мой выбор". ([Согласование числа глагола с несколькими словами в ед. числе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440531/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5))